# Any good example for openGLES shader in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new in OpenGLES. but by googling i got the knowledge about the shader of vertext and the fragment.

now i want to implement it in to my android Application.
So is there any Good And Simple Example to Use Shader in Android OpenGLES ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110702044222/http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/03/13/shaders-android/) is good tutorial for OpenGLES 2.0 shader in android. It's also given step by step develop application. The best option for you would be to read [OpenGL ES 2.0 Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for reply. I need more help if u can ??? I want to set the Android camera preview with that OpenGLES shader in android. So do you know how to implement it ?

Comment: found the [original tutorial on archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20150814013426/http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/03/13/shaders-android/) and then Googled to discover a [copy of it here](https://pixelp3.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/shaders-android/).

Answer (score 6):

[Android Lesson One](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started) from Learn OpenGL ES website is good.

> In this lesson, we’re going to go over the code step-by-step, and look
>   at how to create an OpenGL ES 2 context and draw to the screen. We’ll
>   also take a look at what shaders are and how they work, as well as how
>   matrices are used to transform the scene into the image you see on the
>   screen. Finally, we’ll look at what you need to add to the manifest to
>   let the Android market know that you’re using OpenGL ES 2.

Answer (score 4):

Check the examples that come with Android SDK. There are examples that show how to use shaders with OpenGL ES 2.0.

Like this one:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html

Comment: Ok Now I come to know How to use the Shader file in Android OpenGLES. Will u help me more ? I want to know whether it is Possible to Use that Shader file in Android Camera ??? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847912/is-it-possible-to-give-effect-like-vertex-shader-and-fragment-shader-to-the-andr