# Android - Flip camera android api >= 10

Tags: android, camera, flip

This is my first question.
I need to help for live camera on android.
I want to create camera preview(on surface view). android application for android with some function:

- **Flip mirror camera in live preview camera.** (It's same rotateX or rotateY).

I was try flip bitmap on Camera.PreviewCallback then redraw Surface but it very slow.
Then I try using open cv. But it to larger for my application.

**[Android api >= 10.]**

Give me some idea to fix my prob.
Thanks so much.
// *Sorry for my english.*

Comment: [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html), available for **API >= 11**, let's you performed this really smoothly and easily.

Comment: Thank you so much. But my app need android api >= 10. if I have no way I will use SurfaceTexture :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html), consider hiding the preview surface (you still need a live SurfaceView to launch Camera.startPreview()). Use Camera.PreviewCallback(), push the YUV frames to an OpenGl texture via a shader, and render them in OpenGL. See [Android OpenGL ES process yuv preview as RGBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634887/android-opengl-es-process-yuv-preview-as-rgba) as a starting example.

I strongly suggest to build separate code for API >= 11 with SurfaceTexture, because the system is getting much more strict in enforcing visible live preview with every upgrade. It is still [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653563/hide-camera-preview-but-still-receive-preview-callbacks) to hide the SurfaceView, but for API <= 10 you could simply move it to (10000, 10000) and not use more sophisticated and less robust workarounds.

Comment: Thanks so much :)
Can you give an example SurfaceTexture to display camera ?
I've try but it's not working. I use TextureView to display camera, then I use setRotateY to flip image. What method I use on SurfaceTexture to flip camera ?.

Comment: You can see a minimal example [on GitHub](https://github.com/alexcohn/OpenGLCamera).

Comment: Thank you so much. But in your example you use TextureView => android api >= 14 (it's not 11).

Comment: Oops. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200652/displaying-the-camera-stream-on-a-glsurfaceview-via-surfacetexture