# How add mirror effect in camera preview screen using open camera android

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I want to add mirror effect in live camera preview screen.im using open camera library.can anyone help me to achieve this I'm stuck last couple of days.

Comment: I don't have real experience with Android camera access but do you mean you want to flip the image? In that case this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383244/android-flip-camera-android-api-10. Also, please read [ask] and note that questions need to show more effort on your side, e.g. what research you already conducted or what code you've tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.