# Android OpenGL ES process yuv preview as RGBA

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to use OpenGL to process the data from camera which format is NV21 on Android platform.

My code was below:

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 inputTextureCoordinate;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = position;
   v_texCoord = inputTextureCoordinate;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D yTexture; 
uniform sampler2D uvTexture;
const mat3 yuv2rgb = mat3(
                        1, 0, 1.2802,
                        1, -0.214821, -0.380589,
                        1, 2.127982, 0
                        );

void main() {    
    vec3 yuv = vec3(
                1.1643 * (texture2D(yTexture, v_texCoord).r - 0.0627),
                texture2D(uvTexture, v_texCoord).a - 0.5,
                texture2D(uvTexture, v_texCoord).r - 0.5
                );
    vec3 rgb = yuv * yuv2rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
}
```

I send yTexture:

```
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, w, h, 0,                  GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,                           ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
```

where data was the nv21 format byte array of camera preview
And I send uvTexture:

```
byte[] luminanceAlpha = new byte[w * h / 2];
System.arraycopy(data, w * h, luminanceAlpha, 0, w * h / 2);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,            GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, w / 2, h / 2, 0,                             GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA,                              GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(luminanceAlpha));
```

That's all the code which I thought was important. But when I run the program, I found the result in GLSurfaceView looks more bluer. Is there any wrong with my code. I was very trouble.

Comment: Why do you do 1.1643 * () in your shader? Looks like you are not using the Y texture.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. That's just an input error. I have modified it already.

Comment: Looks all right to me. Are you sure data contains what you expect?

Comment: I have solve this problem. My yuv data is ok. The problem is when I use the method "GLES20.glUniform1i(mGLUniformTexture, 0)" to send uvTexture to opengl, I forget to add the second parameter. So my uvTexture in fragment shader got the wrong value. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TheLordOfRing I know the comment is off topic, but can you please tell me how did you get the content of the camera preview in order to obtain the `yTexture` and `uvTexture`. I am working on a similar application and I cannot figure out how to accomplish this. Thank you.

Comment: Before the camera start preview, you can set PreviewCallback, then the camera data will return by the method onPreviewCallback. It's a byte array and it's format is NV21. You should look up to the NV21 format document and you will see how to copy y channel data and uv channel data. Call me if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using the [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) and generate the [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html), then passing it into camera using [setPreviewTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29)? If you want the pixel RGB data, using [glReadPixels](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) to get the buffer data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. Because SurfaceTexture only support API 11 and above. And I also has a problem when using SurfaceTexture. It will prompt the warning message 'updateTexImage: clearing GL error: 0x502', but this does not affect the rendering. How could I remove the warning?

Comment: Did you try this post [Modifying camera output using SurfaceTexture and OpenGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519235/modifying-camera-output-using-surfacetexture-and-opengl)? I use the [VideoSurfaceview](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/VideoSurfaceView.java) as my render environment and change the MediaPlayer source to camera, and I don't have any warning message.

Comment: I have already saw that, but not the same problem. My warning will not affect the running at all. I just wondering.

Comment: I could only guess that there may be little wrong in your OpenGL ES render setting.
Try that Google's test project as I described above. :)

Comment: I have found the reason. Because I send GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES as GL_TEXTURE_2D, so