# OpenGL on top of camera view

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

I'm trying to find simple examples of using OpenGL with Camera preview. Help me with code examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show camera preview by opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902490/how-to-show-camera-preview-by-opengl)

Comment: these samples don't work

Comment: Mabye [this site](https://digitalbreed.com/2009/11/14/android-render-opengl-on-top-of-camera-preview/) can help you?

Comment: this sample explains how to use Camera (v1) & OpenGl10. I need samples  Camera (v2) & OpenGl20.

Comment: They "don't work" for you because you need to start learning from the basics of OpenGL ES, linear algebra and geometry math; only when you have grasped those topics can you then move on to write and debug the code you want. Letting people here do research for you, only for you to reject it for some specific reason, is not what SO is for.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog i just ask about Rendering OpenGL on top of camera preview

Comment: At this point, perhaps you should pay a visit to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Luxand [FaceSDK](https://www.luxand.com/facesdk/) contains samples for Android using OpenGL to draw image from camera - you can look at the code.